# SQL failover cluster on single ESXi host

Tags: sql-server-2008, vmware-esxi, sql, failovercluster

I'm setting up a virtual environment consisting of 10 VM's with 2 primary SQL databases required. The infrastructure allocates two pairs of SQL 2008 R2 Enterprise edition (VM's). The pairs are recommended in order to achieve redundancy, however there are no specific methods recommended in order to achieve it.

The 10 VM's will be running on a single ESXi host, which is connected via SAS 6Gb HBA to a SAN. I am looking for a recommendation in order to achieve redundancy between the two pairs of SQL databases - would Failover Clustering be the way to go?

Are there any recommendations for configuring this failover cluster with vmdk files?

Comment: Would it not be wise to setup a failover cluster spread over different physical hardware?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/?id=956893

Comment: thanks, we satisfy these requirements from MS. 

@kafka, yes the next step of this setup will be to migrate to different hardware. They still need to get it functional for the next 10-12 months, so we need an interim solution. Thank you.

So far this seem to be a good outline from VMware: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-51-setup-mscs.pdf